# How to actually ignore certain tags?

Tags: discussion, tagging, ignored-tags

This is what it looks like when I "ignore" a tag:

[image: Ignored tag example]

As you can see, the question, rather than being ignored, is just made harder to read, and still takes up just as much room on the "front page".  Here, I'm ignoring the [big-list] tag.  (Am I doing something wrong?)

> **Question**: Is there a way to *actually* ignore questions with certain tags?

This would be quite a problem if one wants to ignore a lot of tags (or more common tags).

Comment: If anyone is reading this years later: you now click on "edit" next to "Ignored Tags" on the home page.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You just go to your profile, click on "prefs", and check "hide ignored tags."

Comment: $\mathrm{Thanks!!!}$